# Brother MFC-J450DW Printer not working on14.04LTS

Tags: printing

I'm a total new to Linux. Loaded a copy of Gnome version Ubuntu and my printer is no longer functioning.  Tried doing a search for drivers and found reference to them on the Brother printer site but I have absolutely no clue how to actually do the install

The brother page tells me to do the following.  I figured out how to open a terminal and paste in the command but it said command not found. And then my head exploded.  Anywhere I can go learn this stuff?

```
 Download the tool.(linux-brprinter-installer-*.*.*-*.gz)
```

The tool will be downloaded into the default "Download" directory.
(The directory location varies depending on your Linux distribution.)
e.g. `/home/(LoginName)/Download`

Step2. Open a terminal window and go to the directory you downloaded the file to in the last step.

Step3. Enter this command to extract the downloaded file:

Command: `gunzip linux-brprinter-installer-*.*.*-*.gz`

Step4. Get superuser authorization with the "su" command or "sudo su" command.

Step5. Run the tool:

Command: `bash linux-brprinter-installer-*.*.*-* Brother machine name`

Step6. The driver installation will start. Follow the installation screen directions.

When you see the message "Will you specify the DeviceURI ?",

```
For USB Users: Choose N(No)
For Network Users: Choose Y(Yes) and DeviceURI.
```

The install process may take some time. Please wait until it is complete.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way for us noobs is to install the drivers from the debs (actually on the Brother website).

http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=mfcj450dw_us&os=128

Just install all of these (just double-click on the file once it's downloaded).  You may need to restart your computer (with the printer plugged in just to be safe), but it should just be plug and play from there.

I had an earlier model and, once doing this, I was able to hotplug (plug it in to a running OS) and print, or run Simple Scan, and it'd *just-work.*